# Add a session variable to a script string?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using the code below to generate a popup box. Where is says "The information is ready to be submitted" I would like to add "Your reference number is 12345" I am getting that reference number using a session i.e. Session("ID").  Is there a way I can add this to the string?

```
    Try
        Dim msg As String = "Hello!"
        Dim script As String = "if(confirm('The information is ready to be submitted')) {window.location.href ='frmMain.aspx'; }"
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, Me.[GetType](), "Test", script, True)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. Just add the information to your script string (I switched the string to stringbuilder for slight efficiency gain):

```
Dim sbScript As New System.Text.StringBuilder(200)

sbScript.Append("if(confirm('The information is ready to be submitted. Your reference number is ").Append(Session("ID"))
sbScript.Append("')) {window.location.href ='frmMain.aspx'; }")
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, Me.[GetType](), "Test", sbScript.ToString(), True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Try
    Dim msg As String = "Hello!"
    Dim idValue As String = CType(Session("ID"), String)
    Dim script As String = "if(confirm('The information is ready to be submitted. Your reference number is " & idValue & "')) {window.location.href ='frmMain.aspx'; }"
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, Me.[GetType](), "Test", script, True)
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
```